# Trigonometric substitution with $\sec{\theta}$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

My question is about the integration technique - trigonometric substitution $x = \sec{\theta},$ with $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$, in accordance with how the inverse secant function is usually defined.

If $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\sqrt{x^2-1} = \tan{\theta}$, and in the last step where we convert the variable from $\theta$ back to $x$, we simply have $\sec{\theta} = x$, $\tan{\theta} = \sqrt{x^2-1}$, $\theta = \sec^{-1}{x}$, etc.

On the other hand, if $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi$, then $\sqrt{x^2-1} = -\tan{\theta}$, and in the last step where we convert the variable from $\theta$ back to $x$, we have $\sec{\theta} = x$, $\tan{\theta} = -\sqrt{x^2-1}$, $\theta = \sec^{-1}{x}$, etc.

A priori, we certainly need to consider each case separately. But what surprises me is that it seems that both cases always give the same final expression. Take $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx$ as an example, if $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, we get $\ln{|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|}+C$, and if $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi$, we get $-\ln{|x-\sqrt{x^2-1}|}+C$ which is equal to $\ln{|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|}+C$.

There are also instances where the final answer does not involve $\ln{|x|}$ (e.g. consider $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx$), so the absolute value bars may not be the explanation.

Therefore, my question is, is it always true that given an integral where such a substitution is applicable, I'll get the same answer whether $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi$? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: The integrand itself contains an unwritten $\pm$ in front of the radical, so integral result contains both the signs. One result s the reciprocal of the other and their logs produce changed signs..

Comment: A common cause of substitution not working is that someone forgets to account for which quadrant they're in when deciding which square root to use (positive or negative) in parts of the substitution. You avoided that mistake. I can't think of an example where a substitution like this does **not** work if you do it as you did. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidK Maybe let me clarify what I want to ask. My question is that it seems like we can always get the answer just by considering the first quadrant. The second quadrant seems to always just yield the same answer. If this is always true, then we can get away with quadrant consideration in this context.

Comment: What do you do when $x \leq -1$?

Comment: OK, I think perhaps I understand the question better now. It's a matter of what is the "same answer." This substitution usually occurs with integrals of functions that have the disconnected domain $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty).$ If you integrate $\sqrt{x^2}/\sqrt{x^2-1}$ with $x=\sec\theta$ you might come up with the result $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ if you look only at the first quadrant of $\theta$, but this is incorrect when $x<0$.

Comment: @DavidK I think this example that you gave exactly answers my question. I failed to find such an example. The two examples I listed in the question statement also have disconnected domain. If you could perhaps explain how you came up with your example / the underlying reason why this example is different from my two examples, I will happily accept your answer.